# Drupal JS on content type

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

Hi I content type 'site_location', /js/site_location.js, and this is on Drupal 7:

I want to run the JS file only on the 'site_location' nodes, but it also runs when I go to the edit page too. Is there any way of not running the javascript when I edit a node of content type 'site_location'?

Here is what I have:

```
function porto_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
   if($vars['node']->type === "site_location"){
      drupal_add_js($theme_path . '/js/site_location.js' , 'file');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just messing around I found a solution.

arg(2) is 'edit' on the edit page and empty on the view page. Therefore I ended up with:

```
  if($vars['node']->type === "site_location" && arg(2) == ''){
```

I still wonder though if there are other approaches to this.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
if ($vars['node']->type === "site_location" && path_is_admin(current_path())) {
  drupal_add_js($theme_path . '/js/site_location.js' , 'file');
}
```